# Reading data from a grid view into text boxes vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm trying to read data retrieved into a gridview out to textboxes. My idea is to hide the gridview as im using it to retrieve data from a table that i need displayed in textboxes but i don't want the gridview to be shown.

So far i have tried this code:

```
Protected Sub btnFindRepair_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFindRepair.Click
    Dim row1 As GridViewRow = GridView1.SelectedRow
    txtFname.Text = row1.Cells(3).Text
    txtLname.Text = row1.Cells(4).Text
    txtContactNum.Text = row1.Cells(5).Text
    txtAltContactNum.Text = row1.Cells(6).Text
    txtAddress.Text = row1.Cells(7).Text
End Sub
```

However this gives me the following error

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_lfjfpvke.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I have checked all of objects and instances and can't seem to find where the null value would come from

This is my gridview code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataKeyNames="Repair_ID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Repair_ID" HeaderText="Repair_ID" SortExpression="Repair_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Booking_Number" HeaderText="Booking_Number" SortExpression="Booking_Number" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Tracking_Number" HeaderText="Tracking_Number" SortExpression="Tracking_Number" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="First_Name" HeaderText="First_Name" SortExpression="First_Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Last_Name" HeaderText="Last_Name" SortExpression="Last_Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact_Number" HeaderText="Contact_Number" SortExpression="Contact_Number" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Alternative_Contact_Number" HeaderText="Alternative_Contact_Number" SortExpression="Alternative_Contact_Number" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer_Address" HeaderText="Customer_Address" SortExpression="Customer_Address" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Customer] WHERE ([Tracking_Number] = @Tracking_Number)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtTrackingNumber" Name="Tracking_Number" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: You can get that error if `SelectedRow` is not set on the GridView. Which is not happening judging from your code.

Comment: @VDWWD in that case then how do i set SelectedRow ?

Comment: `AutoGenerateEditButton="true"`

Comment: @VDWWD Still throws me up the same error unfortunately

Comment: If you are not clicking the edit button and handle that click first, there still will be no row selected. Therefore the error will still remain